# error when using -AppFileTypes in DesktopAppConverter

Tags: desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

Newbie looking for some assistance. I have an app that I have successfully converted using DesktopAppConverter and uploaded to Windows App Store.

However I cannot get my file type associations to work at all. Desktop App Converter produces this error ...

```
 PowerShell Error Record: Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "new"
 and the argument count: "2".
```

when I add -AppFileTypes "'.pg2','.pg3'" to the end of my build command. .pg2 and .pg3 are my custom file types.

My whole command would look something similar to this...

```
DesktopAppConverter.exe -Installer "c:\myAPP" -AppExecutable "myApp.exe" -AppId "xxxxxxxx" -PackagePublisherDisplayName "My App" -PackageName "XXXXmyApp" -AppDisplayName "myAPP" -PackageDisplayName "mYAPP" -Publisher "CN=myPublisherID" -Destination "C:\myAPP\OUTPUT" -Version "vXXX" -Verbose -MakeAppx -Sign -Verify -InstallerArguments "/verysilent" -AppFileTypes "'.pg2','.pg3'"
```

Before I have had success doing this with InnoSetup, but cannot see what I've done wrong here.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Did this error happen when you added -AppFileTypes parameter? If you remove -AppFileTypes and compile it again, will the same issue occur? In addition, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter) to check your command.

Comment: yes error happened when adding the -AppFileTypes, If I remove it the package compiles happily.

Comment: That is the document I was reading..

Comment: Actually DesktopAppConverter has been deprecated. So it is recommended to build package using Visual Studio or the MPT tool. You could try those options to package.